# Wordpress show child pages and sibling pages on the child page

Tags: wordpress

I have a page set up like

Page One
    - Page Red
    - Page Green
    - Page Blue

On Page One I can show the child pages with

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID); 
        ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I show the sibling pages on Page Red, Green and Blue

So on Page Red, Green and Blue I would see Page Red, Page Green, Page Blue

Comment: What happens when you try to use the same code on those other pages?

Comment: I have the code in header.php on Page One it shows Page Red, Page Green and Page Blue. On Page Red, Green or Blue it doesn't show the links to the sibling pages